# repeat column headers on the rdl report table

Tags: report, rdl

I have a rdl report which contains Legend, chart and rows of records below legend and chart. I got a problem here is I can repeat legent and chard for every type new item but I cannot repeat headers for rows of records. I tried with visibility but did not work. headers are simple as row in the table in rdl report which are required to show date, time, position , like that for every record coming database , any suggestions much appreciated

Comment: How exactly do you want to repeat the headers? For every item? For every page?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to repeat header with each row and you are using Visual Studio for designing, it is easy:

Simply click the data row (the one in the middle), right-click it and choose **Insert Row Above**, in that row you can insert your header text and it will repeat with each row record.

If I haven't deciphered your question correctly, please leave a comment.